# Evaluation of && and || in an if statement

Tags: java

I am a little bit confused right now...

I am having an if statement which states:

```
    if(!(line[15].contains("Event_Index")) && line[16].contains("1") && line[18].contains("1") ) {
```

if does not line 15 contains "Event Index" and line 16 does contain a 1 and line 18 does contain a one then go further.

However the if should `not` be executet: if line 15 contains the string event index or line 16 does not contain a 1 or line 18 does not contain a 1.

I wrote it like that:

```
    if( (!(line[15].contains("Event_Index"))) || !(line[16].contains("1")) && !(line[18].contains("1")) ) {
```

However that does not change anything.

I appreciate your reply!

**UPDATE**

The if should be executed if:

1. there is no "Event Index" String
2. there is a 1 in line 16
3. there is a 1 in line 18

Comment: Can you explain what you want with positive logic? When *should* the if block be executed?

Comment: put each condition next to your 1,2,3 list, then put `&&` or `||` between items and done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

- Remove one of the `)`s right after `"Event_Index"` and place it at the end, after `!(line[18].contains("1")`.
- Put the `!` immediately after `if(`.
- Remove the rest of the `!`s.
- Remove the redundant `()`s

Like this:

```
if(!(line[15].contains("Event_Index") || line[16].contains("1") && line[18].contains("1"))) {
```